# Object not serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, serialization

i have a fileupload control in asp.net, used to upload images. i want to show preview the image in `image` control of asp.net. here is the aspx code

**ASPX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function FU_Img_onchange(oFU_Img) {
        alert("sak");
        var img = document.getElementById("<%= Btn_Preview.ClientID%>");
        img.click();

    }
    function FU_Video_onchange(oFU_Vid) {
        var vid = document.getElementById("<%= VidPreview.ClientID %>");
        vid.click();
    }
</script>
```

**C# code behind**

```
 protected void Btn_Preview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (FU_Img.HasFile)
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath("/TempImages");


                    FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(FU_Img.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string fileName = oFileInfo.Name;

                    string fullFileName = path + "//" + fileName;
                    string imagePath = "/TempImages/" + fileName;

                    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    }
                    Session["FileUpload"] = FU_Img;
                    FU_Img.PostedFile.SaveAs(fullFileName);
                    Img_Prof.ImageUrl = imagePath;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/log.txt"))
                {
                    sw.NewLine = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "--->>" + ex.ToString() + "\n" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

as you can see, i am putting my image control in session. it works fine on development server. when i posted the site to domain i get the issue

`Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.`

**Stack Trace**

```
[SerializationException: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +7738443
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +258
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +111
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) +422
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) +51
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +410
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +134
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1577

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.]
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1662
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +34
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter writer) +606
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData item, Stream stream) +239
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length) +72
   System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem) +87
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +560
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75`
```

I am sure there is something wrong with fileupload control and session. But please guide in proper direction what should i do?
thanks in advance

Comment: The stack trace and message clearly state the problem: you are either using StateServer or a database to store session data, which means it must be serialized to be stored in either location. The FileUpload control you are attempting to stick in session is not serializable, so it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By seeing the exception , it may be possible that SessionMode is set to SQLServer or StateServer , Change it to InProc and see if its works. If it works that means your Session Persistance into backend store is not working so check that out also or post the code so that we can drill more about the problem.

Comment: Nothing like `<sessionState />` was in my `web.config`, by default it might be StateServer or SQLServer. I cahnged it to `InProc`. It worked for me.

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri: A Khatri if its worked and you need it as InProc than accept the answer :)

Comment: What you mean by Session Persistance. Please let me know.